# Is there a way to get Lightroom to extract only part of the folder name on export?

Tags: lightroom, file-management, import

I have the photos for the newspaper I'm working at stored in folders named like "YY-MM-DD_name-of-article". I have a folder for each article. Now, in our editorial system, they want them named like "DDMMYY_name-of-article_resort_journalist" and I want to achieve that with the least amount of effort.
I got journalist, resort, MM and YY figured out using a preset during export. For the DD part I'm entering a Date manually (using the add custom text box in the export preset), because the convention specifies that I have to use the date the article will be published which is usually not the current day (so no way to enter this automatically into the filename using the current date feature). The problem comes in with the name of the article: I don't want to enter this name again and I can't, because the add custom text box is already filled with the publishing date. So I have it set up to use the folder name, because it also contains the article name. But it also contains the Date in a reverse order, so after export, my files are named like this: "DDMMYY_YY-MM-DD_name-of-article_resort_journalist". And the people at the newspaper don't want to have this additional YY-MM-DD in their filenames. So the question is:

**TL;DR** Is there a way to tell Lightroom to extract **only the characters after the underscore in the folder name the exported pictures are in** and put that into the file during export. That would solve the problem of the additional YY-MM-DD appearing in the filename. I know that I could do this manually, but it is a huge pain and I usually don't have the time.

Answer (score 1):

Probably better off just using a tool specializing in this issue. For windows I would recommend Renamer or Bulk Rename Utility.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change how you create and name the folders? Since your output doesn't use the dates from the folders, either eliminate the dates in the folders, or have a date folder be a parent folder. This way when you export it will only pick up the article name.

I assume you want the image date in the folder for your personal preference, but it is impacting your workflow...so change it.

Example:

Current folder="DDMMYY_name-of-article_resort_journalist" > results in> "DDMMYY_YY-MM-DD_name-of-article_resort_journalist"

New folders = DDMMYY/"name-of-article_resort_journalist" > results in> "YY-MM-DD_name-of-article_resort_journalist"